# External hard drive freezes everything

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, freeze

When I insert my external hard drive my computer freezes. By freezes I mean :

- I can't open the hard drive, when I try to windows explorer freezes and it forces me to end process, when I do that whole laptop goes into a freeze mode till I remove the hard drive.
- I can't create a new folder on the desktop for example (idiot example but it explains the issue), when I do nothing happens, if I remove the hard drive the folder gets created, as if everything I do after plugging the USB cord of my HDD goes on hold.
- When I open the diskmgmt and then plugging my HDD and refresh it, it becomes not responding till I remove the HDD.
- All tools that try to read the HDD (in order to scan it, get from it information... etc) freeze and stop working till I unplug the HDD

Any idea what's wrong with my poor HDD? How to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Did you already test your HDD in *other machine*? Also test the HDD with *other USB cable*. If those steps didn't work probably that your HDD could be damaged, then you must try to run some diagnostic app like [Crystal Disk Info](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/).

Comment: [How to Use Crystal Disk Info - Get detailed information about your hard drive & solid-state drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXOqGbnkrGY)

Comment: Either the HDD is mechanically damaged (most likely) or the external case has an issue. To determine if the HDD has physical damage, you'll need to use `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` via either a Linux PC or an Ubuntu Install USB _(easiest - download the Ubuntu Desktop ISO, create a bootable USB via [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), Boot the USB, choose Try Ubuntu)_ > `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install smartmontools` > determine disk via `ls /dev | grep sd` > `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` _(where `<disk>` is `sda`, `sdb`, etc. After the S.M.A.R.T info, it will list when the damage occurred

Comment: I'll try these comments and get back to you!

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy Did you have any success with this problem?

Comment: @AndrewMorton nope, never really found out why, I eventually gave up thinking it was the hard drive that was physically damaged.

Answer (score 0):

All the symptoms are possible indicators for a mechanical issue or surface damage due to for example a head crash. Windows is very ill equipped to handle such issues, specially when read errors occur in that it considers file system meta data.

Eventually such drives may go off-line due to either firmware crash or more intentional after setting device fault bit. Only a power-cycle gets them going again.

Any attempt to access the drive may as well be further deteriorating it's condition, so avoid experiments. Make every read count. Do not use in-place hard drive repair tools (chkdsk, SpinRite etc.).

Ideally you clone the drive using a tool that's designed for the purpose of copying/imaging 'unstable' drives. Note that there's always the risk you're further damaging the drive!

- ddrescue is such a tool
- HDDSuperClone is considered even better and some times even used by data recovery professionals. It was a commercial tool that is now open-source. Data recovery pro's consider it closest thing to a professional hardware/software based disk imaging solution (https://www.recoveryforce.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=274). Possibly for OP's drive it needs to be combined with a power-relay to power-cycle the drive.

If the drive contains vital data that you can not afford to lose a data recovery specialist may be a better option. Consider sending it in for (an often free) diagnosis.

He/she will use specially designed hardware disk cloning/images tools that allow for firmware manipulations to facilitate recovery (examples: disable sector reallocation, clear defects lists and temporarily disable specific heads). Power-cycling the drive is often also an option implemented.

If the drive is really bad 'targeted' cloning can be even considered and performed using those tools. For even worse drives some times cleanroom work may be required prior to cloning the drive (to clean debris and swap heads for example).

Answer (score -2):

The first thing I would do is try the external HDD in another port to see if that helps; if unsuccessful, try the following:

1. Run the following, where `E:` is the external HDD volume label:

   ```powershell
   ChkDsk E: /f /r
   ```
2. Try uninstalling the external HDD and USB mass storage device from *Device Manager*

   - External HDD is listed under *Disk Drives* and USB mass storage device under *Universal Serial Bus Controllers*
   - To see these items listed in Device Manager when the external HDD is disconnected: 
      *Device Manager* > *View* > *Show Hidden Devices*
3. Restart the computer, then reconnect the external HDD

Comment: Please use correct markdown when creating an answer... see the formatting toolbar or help icon.

Comment: I'd already tried those, they didn't work.

Comment: chkdsk is bad idea. if we assume a mechanical issue or surface damage due for example head crash, chkdsk push the drive 'over the edge'. most common enclosure issues don't cause this behavior. to rule out drive issues simply try the drive on/in different PC.

Comment: drive - *driver* issues I meant to say, too late to edit ..